# Embed YouTube, login to buy & payment methods

Tags: plugins

As you can probably tell, I'm new to WooCommerce and WordPress in general.

Before I start building a site and buying plugins and extension I would like to know:

- Can you easily embed YouTube videos onto product pages with WooCommerce?
- Does the customer have to log in or create an account to buy an item through WooCommerce?
- Can a customer pay via credit or debit card through PayPal and not have a paypal account when using WooCommerce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Woocommerce docs:

> WooCommerce includes options to allow guest checkout, meaning
>   customers do not need an account to make a purchase;

Paypal standard merchant functionality permits people to use credit or debit card instead of a paypal account.

WooCommerce is based on custom post types, and uses the standard editor field, so embedding a youtube video in your product would be just as easy as adding a video to a blog post.